# Dynamically recalculating land use classes/number of pixels per class

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, openlayers, wcs

I have a land use raster dataset (GeoTIFF) that I've published on geoserver. I am able to display it using both leaflet and OpenLayers using their respective WMS methods.

What I need to do is to recalculate the land use classes/number of pixels per class, at different zoom levels. I have been researching it, and have realized that I would probably have to use WCS or WPS. But I am unable to find any example, that can help me figure out how to handle these services.

Can anyone guide me on how to integrate these services with OpenLayers or Leaflet?

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "recalculate the land use classes/number of pixels per class"? Please elaborate.

Comment: I currently created a land-use map with multiple classes for the whole region. So let's say at full scale, the Grassland & shrubland is 82,580.27 & Waterbody is15,648.60 sq. km.  But these are the values at the State level. If the user selects a city or district within the state, the values change. How can we dynamically "play around " with these values? Basically, at this stage of the project, I just want to be able to access the pixel values stored within the geotiff...

Comment: Clip the raster to the county/municipality/city polygon: read https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/cutting_merging.html . Then vectorize each clipped raster (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html ) and calculate areas from the resulting vector dataset.

Comment: I know that. I need this done dynamically. On my web application. I am assuming I can do this through WPS or WCS. If yes, can you guide me on how to handle these services?

Comment: could be done with WCPS, but AFAIK, GeoServer doesn't support WCPS; you may look at rasdaman